# Adding custom number class to Python int results in "TypeError"

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, typeerror, magic-methods

Is there a way to be able to add an instance of a Python class to an integer (default `int` class). For example, if I have a class with magic methods:

```py
class IntType:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __add__(self, other):
        return self.value + other

# Works
print(IntType(10) + 10)

# Doesn't Work
print(10 + IntType(10))
```

I can't add my `IntType` to the built-in `int` class. If I try to add `IntType` to an integer, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 8, in <module>
    print(10 + IntType(10))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'IntType'
```

The only way I can think of to get this to work is to somehow change the `int` class' `__add__` method. If you are wondering why I don't just add the `int` to the `IntType` (e.g. `IntType(10) + 10`) is because I need this to work for all operators, for example subtraction (where the order is important). I'm using Python 3.

Comment: The left operand is the one that defines *\_\_add\_\_*. For that to work, you'd have to overwrite *int*'s. And you should do `return self.value + other.value` if you want it to work for 2 *IntType*s.

Comment: Is this the only way I could do this? The problem with doing this is that now, if I distribute my program, it becomes ten times harder, because I have to find a way to go into the python internals and change the `__add__` method.

Comment: @CristiFati If I added the `return  self.value + other.value`, I wouldn't be able to add normal integers to the modified integer class because it has no attribute `value`, so I would have to use `try except`'s to make it work, which is slower.

Comment: @MonLiH you can check what class `other` belongs to, so that your class works both with `TypeInt` and `int` -> `return self.value + other if isinstance(other, int) else self.value + other.value`.

Comment: @jfaccioni Your right I can...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implementing reverse addition (`__radd__`) for your `IntType` class should fix this:

```
>>> class IntType: 
...     def __init__(self, value): 
...         self.value = value 
... 
...     def __add__(self, other): 
...        return self.value + other 
...
...     def __radd__(self, other): 
...         return self.value + other 

>>> IntType(10) + 10 == 10 + IntType(10)
True
```

This is the operation that Python tries to use when all else fails (i.e, `int.__add__(IntType)` is not a defined operation).

Comment: This worked! Although I used `return other + self.value` to preserve the order. (For subtraction and division)

Comment: You can also simply implement the reverse addition in terms of the regular addition (at least for mathematical operations in which the other doesn't matter): `def __radd__(self, other): return self.__add__(other)`